# Module::Install requires and skipping a version

Tags: perl, dependencies

I have the following requirement for a Perl application

```
requires 'Net::DNS'                      => 0;
```

Now, version 1.03 of `Net::DNS` is broken (see [Not a GLOB reference at ...IO/Select.pm line 61](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846179/not-a-glob-reference-at-io-select-pm-line-61/33846324#33846324) and [#108745: Net::DNS::Resolver bgsend](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=108745))  and I would like to skip it. Is there a way to say that?

- either that the version should be smaller than 1.03?
- or that that the version could be smaller than 1.03 or bigger?

Comment: Are you open to programatic checks, or does it have to be a one-liner require?

Comment: A one liner would be nice. But a programmatic one is also OK.

Comment: I'll put a solution down, and work on some sample code and edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```perl
my $ver = eval { require Net::DNS; $Net::DNS::VERSION };

if (!$ver || $ver eq '1.03') {
    requires 'Net::DNS' => '1.04';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the module using require, possibly using eval if necessary to avoid errors if it doesn't exist. For most CPAN modules, you can check the $VERSION variable of the module to see if the loaded version is what you expect. If not, exit or otherwise handle the problem as you see fit.

```
BEGIN
{
    require Net::DNS;
    if ($Net::DNS::VERSION == 1.03) {
        print STDERR "Error: Net::DNS version 1.03 loaded\n";
        exit 1;
    }
 }
```